# Detect data change in Mongodb using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to detect data change in mongodb from node.js? The use case goes like this
- Have a callback function which is called once "ArticleViews" field in mongo reaches certain number. The callback function might use socket to update browser.

Essentially, can I have a callback function which will be called once certain data in the mongodb changes.

Is this possible? Or is there any other way to achieve similar effect?

Edit: mongo oplog does give changes in documents but I would like to have a callback function of node.js to be invoked on a change. Like, when a specific record is changed, a node.js callback function should be invoked with the changed data as the function parameter. I would use this functionality in my web app where user will be notified realtime using websockets about the change in mongodb document.

Comment: Would querying to oplog solves your issue? Any changes like insert, update and delete are logged in oplog.rs.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is generally possible to get a callback when there are changes made in the collection through insert, update and delete.
First you need to enable the oplog in mongodb. All changes are reflected in this collection. Oplogs belong to local database. You can create a tailable cursor over oplog and stream the data through a socket. Any changes will be read through this cursor.

The following blog would help you achieve this task.

[quering oplog in nodejs](https://blog.compose.io/the-mongodb-oplog-and-node-js/)